# merging template specializations for const and non-const std::list

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization

Is there an easy way to merge both template specializations into a single one, perhaps using `std::enable_if`, for the following MWE?

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class A {
    // ...
};
class B {
    // ...
};

template<typename T> class C {};

template<typename T>
class C<std::list<T> &> : public A, public B
{
    std::list<T> &l_ref;
public:
    C(std::list<T> &lr) : l_ref{lr} { }
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
class C<const std::list<T> &> : public A, public B
{
    const std::list<T> &l_ref;
public:
    C(const std::list<T> &lr) : l_ref{lr} { }
    // ...
};
```

For the idiomatic

```
template<typename T>
struct C<T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, std::list<E> &>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, const std::list<E> &>::value>::type>
    : public A, public B
{
    // ...
```

way, I see no way to make `E` deducible or to specify the type of "any `std::list`".

Comment: Do you mean you want to write one template but for both `const` and non-`const` versions? Do they behave the same?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a traits, first, then use SFINAE, something like:

```
template <typename T> struct is_a_stdlist_ref : std::false_type {};
template <typename ... Ts>
struct is_a_stdlist_ref<std::list<Ts...>&> : std::true_type {};
template <typename ... Ts>
struct is_a_stdlist_ref<const std::list<Ts...>&> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename Enabler = void> struct C;

template<typename T>
struct C<T, std::enable_if_t<is_a_stdlist_ref<T>::value>>
    : public A, public B
{
    //...
};
```

Comment: @T.C.: unneeded indeed, removed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to merge both template specializations into a single one, perhaps using std::enable_if, for the following MWE?

Do you accept a solution without `std::enable_it` ?

To make the solution more flexible, I propose to define a type traits, `specIndex`, to fix a type dependant index, where `0` is "generic type", `1` is "std::list &`or`const`, and other integer can refer to other specializations

```
template <typename>
struct specIndex
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 0U }; }; // generic version

template <typename T>
struct specIndex<std::list<T> &>
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 1U }; }; // pro lists

template <typename T>
struct specIndex<std::list<T> const &>
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 1U }; }; // pro lists
```

Next step is add a default template integer parameter for `C`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t = specIndex<T>::value>
class C
 { };
```

The last step is to define the index 1 (`std::list<T> &` or constant) specialization

```
template<typename T>
class C<T, 1U> : public A, public B
 {
   private:
      T & l_ref;

   public:
      C (T & lr) : l_ref{lr}
       { std::cout << "- list version" << std::endl; }
 };
```

The following is a full example

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
 { };

class B
 { };

template <typename>
struct specIndex
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 0U }; }; // generic version

template <typename T>
struct specIndex<std::list<T> &>
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 1U }; }; // pro lists

template <typename T>
struct specIndex<std::list<T> const &>
 { static constexpr std::size_t value { 1U }; }; // pro lists

template <typename T, std::size_t = specIndex<T>::value>
class C
 { };

template<typename T>
class C<T, 1U> : public A, public B
 {
   private:
      T & l_ref;

   public:
      C (T & lr) : l_ref{lr}
       { std::cout << "- list version" << std::endl; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::list<long>  sll;

   C<int>                     a;
   C<std::list<long> &>       b{sll};
   C<std::list<long> const &> c{sll};
 }
```